# SVN export but exclude certain files?

Tags: linux, svn

I need to export my checked-in codebase on the production server, but need to exclude certain files from being overwritten.

Is there a way of "exporting" (or equivalent) content (without the .svn folders, etc that are created) and excluding certain files?

What I do presently is export everything and do the changes manually, but am thinking of exporting to a clean directory, copying the necessary files and changing the directory name to the correct one.

Comment: does the list of files you are pulling from the repo changes for every update ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a patch with your changes:

```
svn export . /tmp/exported
cp -pr /tmp/exported /tmp/exported.orig
# do your changes to /tmp/exported
cd /tmp
diff -urNP exported.orig exported > "$HOME"/local-changes.patch
```

Then when you do export then first export then apply changes:

```
svn export . /tmp/exported --force
( cd /tmp/exported; patch -p1 < "$HOME"/local.changes.patch )
```

This way you'll get an error, when your modified files would change so much that your changes will not apply cleanly. If you just copy files then if, for example, a configuration option will be added to configuration file, then your system will break mysteriously.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you use to access your SVN command (command-line svn? Tortoise? Eclipse SVN plugin?)

With Tortoise SVN, to export : right-click in your repo -> ToirtoiseSVN -> export.
With Tigris Eclipse plugin, to ignore file : right-click on your file -> Team -> add to svn:ignore ; to export : right-click on your trunk (or repo) -> Team -> Export

Comment: tortoisesvn for checking in. command-line on redhat/centos for exporting. Can I do what you're saying above via the commandline? I dont want to make it a permanent ignore, just for this operation...

Comment: Tortoise SVN is based on SVN commandline, so, I believe you can do the export with that. After a small research I found that : `/svn-export revision-from revision-to repository target-directory`

Comment: revision-from is the revision you want to "save", revision-to is the new revision repository is the repository in question (ie : svn://localhost/trunk) target-directory is self-explanatory I think

Comment: Or there : `svn export -r Rev-Number http://node-name/path` is much better for your case. Source : http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/Subversion.html But I don't think you can ignore file temporarily for an export. But I can be wrong

Comment: @matt_tm and finally : you can still make a branch with all file you want to export and without file you want to ignore. Since, it seems you don't need modification on those ignored file, it doesn't matter if it's in the branch or not and you can work in this branch in the future...